# SyntaxError: Unexpected token catch { ^

Tags: angular-cli, node-modules

```
        node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\host.js:25
                    catch {
                          ^
        
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
            at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
            at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
            at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
            at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:11:18
```

"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
"@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
"blob-util": "^2.0.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"mydatepicker": "^2.0.8",
"ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
"ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
"ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
"ng2-tooltip-directive": "^1.3.7",
"primeng": "4.3.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
"xlsx": "^0.14.5",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
}

```
"devDependencies": {
                "@angular/cli": "^12.1.0",
                "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
                "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
                "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
                "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
                "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
                "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
                "karma": "~1.4.1",
                "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
                "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
                "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
                "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
                "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
                "protractor": "~5.1.0",
                "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
                "tslint": "~4.5.0",
                "typescript": "^2.2.0"
              }
        
I tried uninstalling and installing typescript and @angular/cli and deleted node modules, couldn't solve it. Any help how can I get rid off TIA!
```

Comment: I suspect this is caused by using incompatible versions of nodejs and angular-cli. Refer to this table to see which versions work together: https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your package.json file.
Also i couldn't see @angular-devkit/build-angular in dev dependencies. If this isn't there try installing it by following command.

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: hi, that didn't work for me!! updated the dependencies

Comment: @shekar, why xlo version is 12 and rest others have version 4. Did you just upgrade cli itself? Version mismatch can also cause this perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue after trying to update angular versions, and resolved it by using a newer version of node.